# Expo Web is not bundling everything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, expo, effector

I am starting a React / React Native project that uses Expo. I am using effector / effector-react for state management. All other dependencies were working well. However, after adding effector / effector-react, the React Native apps continue to work well, however, the Web is no longer working due to bundling issues are given by these errors:

```
Web Bundling failed ...ms
Unable to resolve "effector" from "..."

Web Bundling failed ...ms
Unable to resolve "effector-react" from "..."
```

I'm starting the server application using `npx expo start --web`

Comment: This post currently includes multiple questions. It should focus on one only.

Comment: Adjusted. The major goal of course is to fix it, however I thought if I can at least find a verbose mode, I can may be self-serve or at least have more information to play with

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you use 'Redux' for state management. The use of store, action, and reducer would make it relatively easy for you.

In case you don't want to use Redux, make sure you have installed the effector effector-react properly using the following command:

```
npm install --save effector effector-react
```

Comment: I wished to use effector for reasons arguable outside this thread. In my current Expo project, RN bundles it and it works in the apps. Previously, elsewhere, I have used in both CRA and Next and it works there too. 

In my current Expo project, I tried installing via both (1)```npx expo install effector effector-react``` and (2)```npm install --save effector effector-react``` (actually it runs (1) inside (2) as well behind the scenes as evident in the console logs).

I believe the issue is something to do with the Webpack version and/or configuration, which I have no idea about.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).